# Is there a way to profile a CUDA kernel from another CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, gpu, side-channel-attacks

I am trying to perform a side-channel attack on a GPU, and I am trying to find out if there is a way to profile a "victim" GPU kernel from a "spy" GPU kernel. It could be anything, like execution time, memory allocation, etc. So, I want a method to get statistics about another kernel in CUDA C++. Is this possible? I want it to be within my code, and not by seeing results from Nsight Compute.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do much things from a CUDA kernel. Generally, timings are recorded by the GPU and available to the host (certainly thanks to the driver) and AFAIK timers are not available from the kernel. Note that I expect Nvidia to fix such vulnerability if it would be well known anyway (though this is often not easy without impacting performance or the accuracy of timers)... Since the L2 cache is shared as well as memory it might be possible to get some information but not as useful as on CPU since GPUs hide a lot the latency of instructions.

Comment: I advise you to read the state of the art of *research papers*. A quick naive search results in [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3579371.3589080).